# Not able to access parameter sent from Controller to Model in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I have a controller in which I am attempting to pass an associative array to my model, which will then take that array and insert it into my database.  However, when I pass the array $finalResults to the model, and I try to access in it the foreach statement, I get the error that "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" indicated on first foreach statement. I am still new to codeIgniter, so I am unsure what is causing this.

My Controller:

```
class Test extends CI_Controller {

    public function getResults(){

        $this->load->model('Test_model');
        $this->load->database();

        $finalResults = $this->input->post('answers');

        $data['finalResults'] = $finalResults;

        $this->Test_model->processResults($finalResults);
    }
}
```

My Model:

```
class Test_model extends CI_Model{

  public function processResults($finalResults){

      foreach ($finalResults as $question){
          foreach($question as $key => $value){
             $data_to_insert = array(
               $key => $value
             );
           }
       }
       $this->db->insert('result', $data_to_insert);
   }
}
```

I know that this is pretty far off from a full solution, but this error is keeping me from getting any further.  Any help with it is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try confirming that you are indeed passing an associative array into the `foreach` loop?

Add a condition check for `is_array()` prior to the loop.

```
if(is_array($finalResults))
    foreach($finalResults as $question){
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: That was the issue.  I had forgot to json_decode the input from ajax before sending it forward.  Thank you for the help!  Now if I could just get the insert to work...